# Как программно делать свайпы на Android?

Tags: android

Подскажите, есть, допустим, PDF Reader и мне нужно реализовать перелистывания с другого устройства. Со всем я, вроде бы, разобрался, но как программно можно делать свайпы на устройстве, если запущено не мое приложение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программно эмулировать свайп можно используя shell команду: `shell input swipe`

```
adb shell input swipe x1 y1 x2 y2 sss
```

`x1` — начальные координаты по горизонтали

`y1` — начальные координаты по вертикали

`x2` — конечные координаты по горизонтали

`y2` — конечные координаты по вертикали

`sss` — время выполнения в миллисекундах

Исходная статья

P.S. Пример запуска shell из приложения:

```
Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input swipe 10 20 30 40 100");
```

но тут возможно нужен root

P.P.S понятно, что выполнять придётся из фона